# Regarding Data table source data access

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used the datatable ajax call for listing I received the below json data in ajax call:

```
{ 
    "sEcho":1,
    "iTotalRecords":"1",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords":"1",
    "aaData":[
        ["Demo to Mam","2"]
    ],
    "countOfTotalRecords":2
}
```

How I can use the `countOfTotalRecords` var value on view page?

Answer (score 1):

You've to decode your JSON data using json_decode, then you have an object. Looks something like this:

```
$json = '{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"1","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["Demo to Mam","2"]],"countOfTotalRecords"
:2}';

$decode = json_decode($json);

echo $decode->countOfTotalRecords; // this will display 2, regarding your data
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
 $str = '{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"1","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["Demo to Mam","2"]],"countOfTotalRecords":2}';

 $arr = json_decode($str);

 $tcount = $arr->countOfTotalRecords;

 echo $tcount;
```

Comment: I am used database direct echo the output as listing, How I can access then?

Comment: Like -> 'sAjaxSource': 'index.php?mode=reports-sms&action=ajaxResponse'